# Sample Submission on Boston Housing Dataset

Tags: machine-learning, dataset, prediction, kaggle

I want to enter my submission for the competition at 
https://www.kaggle.com/c/boston-dataset/data. But as it turns out there is sample Submission file.

Now I have tried removing column names, index but keep getting different errors.

[Error snip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2C7a6.png)

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try this snippet:

```
submission = pd.DataFrame({ 'ID': test_data.ID.values, 'medv': predictions })
submission.to_csv("submission.csv", index=False)
```

where `predictions` is a list of your predictions for the test set.